# Trying to join two tables, display null fields as extra rows, and make those null values 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have two tables.

```
select distinct id, doc
from images
```

which looks like:

```
 ID     |   DOC
--------------------
GROWG       APP
GROWG       BACKGR
MAXAR       APP
MAXAR       BACKGR
MAXAR       LIC
```

and

```
select DriverID
from drivers
```

which looks like

```
DriverID
--------
GROWG
ZULLY
MAXAR
JILLX
```

What I want to my end result to look like when I either use a temp table or a select statement is to make it look like this:

```
DriverID     |     Doc     |     Count
-----------------------------------------
GROWG              APP             1
GROWG              BACKGR          1
GROWG              LIC            **NULL** (or 0)
MAXAR              APP             1
MAXAR              BACKGR          1
MAXAR              LIC             1
```

So in the end it it is recognizing that there is a total of 3 different type of documents and it shows that GROWG is missing his document for "LIC"

Can anyone help?

Comment: What does `drivers` have to do with the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select id.id, doc.doc, count(i.id) as cnt
from (select distinct id from images) as id cross join
     (select distinct doc from images) doc left outer join
     images i
     on i.id = id.id and i.doc = doc.doc;
```

It returns all the combinations of `id` and `doc` from `images`, along with the count for the table.  It returns `0` if the combination doesn't exist.

EDIT:

TO check for a match to `drivers`, you can just add:

```
where id in (select driverid from drivers)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: Oh and the reason I wanted drivers linked to it is to check to see if the drivers are employeed drivers. I forgot to mention that portion. I'll be using the Driver table to check if they are employeed then compare it to the images table to see what image files they are missing.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified the above query from Gordon Linoff. Check this

```
 select id.driverid, doc.doc, count(i.id) as cnt
from (select distinct driverid from drivers) as id cross join
     (select distinct doc from images) doc left outer join
     images i
     on i.id = id.driverid and i.doc = doc.doc 
     where id.driverid in (select id from images )
     group by id.driverid,doc.doc;
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can select only the 0 values?

Comment: For 0 values of 'GROWG' add
     having count(i.id)=0
after group by clause.